# How to customize update folder information service in webcenter content

Tags: oracle-ucm

I have to add custom field into folder information popup. when we clicking on the "Update Folder Information"

[image]

How to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Metadata fields are configured in the Configuration Manager (Administration -> Admin Applets -> Configuration Manager -> Information Fields). But...
Folders can't carry metadata like documents can. If you configure a metadata field, it won't be part of the folder configuration. It will only let you set default metadata for documents put in that folder.

Comment: Sam, you are right but my requirement is  how do we add field in above folder edit form so we can display folderfolders column.

Comment: That requires some fairly heavy customization. Start with a custom component (read up on that if you've never done it before). Customize the FLD_EDIT_FOLDER_FORM service to pick up the field you need from the database. Then comes the template customization, which is tricky at best. Now you have to do all this for the other cases as well.